# Fold over effect using CSS3

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am trying to create the following effect on my div. I could achieve the result using a background image, however, I'd like to see if there is a way to do this using a responsive CSS3 method.

[image]

My current HTML and CSS looks like this:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.container {
  background: red;
}
.item {
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h1>Content Header</h1>
    <p>Body Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've done a lot of searching but I'm not sure what you'd call this effect? Fold over paper effect?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using border-radius, a pseudo-element and some linear/radial-gradient:

```css
body {
  background: grey;
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  background: red;
}

.item {
  position:relative;
  background: 
    linear-gradient( 160deg, blue 60%,transparent 60.5%) right,
    linear-gradient(-160deg, blue 60%,transparent 60.5%) left;
  background-size:50.2% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 80px auto 50px;
  padding: 20px 20px 100px;
  color:#fff;
}
.item:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:100%;
  height:20px;
  right:0;
  left:-20px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, #ccc 20px, transparent 21px), 
    blue;
  border-radius:20px 20px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h1>Content Header</h1>
    <p>Body Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```